# Adding Replica Set Members error in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

i got error like this! Please advice me what should i do? I finished editing /etc/hosts with the one i will add to the primary! But it shown as errrors as below!

```
rs2:PRIMARY> rs.add("192.168.56.101:27017")
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Quorum check failed because not enough voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting nodes responded: 192.168.56.104:27017; the following nodes did not respond affirmatively: 192.168.56.101:27017 failed with Connection refused",
    "code" : 74
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongod server with IP `192.168.56.101:27017` must be configured with a replicaSet.

Start mongod on `192.168.56.101:27017` with replicaSet option like:

```
mongod --replSet "rs2"
```

Comment: Thanks sir ! It solved! And then I can't get data from primary node when i try in seconday --> Error msg is "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false"!

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer. To read data from secondary servers you need to execute the command rs.setSlaveOk() in the secondary mongo console

Comment: Thanks sir! But if i didn't execute the command in the secondary console, did the data not replicate automatically?

Comment: Data will automatically replicate if the replication setup is fine. You only need to execute the command to read from secondary(the command is valid for that session only).

Comment: So, is there any ways to know is it worked well or replicated is well? Any commands?

Comment: rs.status() can give you information about your replicaSet.

Comment: or you can run this command db.adminCommand( { replSetGetStatus : 1 } )